# Gradle failed to resolve: com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:3.2.1

Tags: android, firebase, gradle, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

**Gradle sync failed as com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:3.2.1 is not resolved**

I'm using the latest dependencies for Firebase and google play services. Tried enabling signIn options from Firebase console. Also, added google-services.json under app directory. Still, the same error on gradle sync

Here's the app and project level gradle files:

app/build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'com.google.firebase.example.fireeats'
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName '1.0'

        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    // Firestore
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:11.8.0'

    // Other Firebase/Play services deps
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.8.0'

    // FirebaseUI (for authentication)
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:3.2.1'

    // ButterKnife (for sample code brevity)
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.7.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.7.0'

    // Support Libs
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:27.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:customtabs:27.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:27.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.0.1'

    // Android architecture components
    compile 'android.arch.lifecycle:runtime:1.0.0-alpha9'
    compile 'android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.0.0-alpha9'
    annotationProcessor 'android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:1.0.0-alpha9'

    // Third-party libraries
    compile 'me.zhanghai.android.materialratingbar:library:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

project/build.gradle

// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
        jcenter()
        google()
        mavenLocal()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**Edit:** Changing FirebaseUI Version from 3.2.1 to 3.1.3 worked. Here's the github page for FirebaseUI - https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android which lists FirebaseUI Version against Firebase/Play Services Version. Though it maps FirebaseUI version 3.2.1 to Firebase/Play Services Version 11.8.0, it didn't work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here in your gradle

Add this dependency,

```
 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.8.0'
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:3.1.3'
```

Answer (score 0):

for me, when I changed all the google-play-services and firebase services to 11.0.8. It worked.

but I do not know where is the exact problem.

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:11.0.8'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.0.8'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:11.0.8'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.0.8'
```

Answer (score 0):

update your gradle

Add this dependency,

```
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:7.2.0'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-storage:7.2.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

I am able to rectify this error by using below line

```
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:7.2.0'
```

Please note : The FirebaseUI Auth SDK has transitive dependencies on the Firebase SDK and the Google Play services SDK
so with above line also

```
implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:30.1.0')
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth-ktx'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:20.2.0'
```